# Add sequence numbers to FASTA headers

Tags: perl, shell, awk

I have a file of FASTA sequences, each starting with a different header. I need to add sequence numbers starting with 1 (Seq1, Seq2, Seqn...) for each sequence header. Here are the first three:

input:

```
>[organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
>[organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
>[organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
```

output:

```
>Seq1 [organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
>Seq2 [organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
>Seq3 [organism=Fowl Adenovirus] Fowl Adenovirus FAdV hexon gene, isolate FAdV/SP/1184/2013
AACTGGATCGCGGAAGACGGTAACAAGACAACCATCACCGGACAAATGTCTAA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One awk:

```
awk '/^>/{gsub(/^>/,">Seq"i++" ");}1' i=1 file
```

Comment: This can be simplified to: `awk '/^>/{sub(/^>/,">Seq"++i" ");}1' file`; using GNU awk, you can also perform an "in-place" edit using the "-i inplace" option.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/>/> /' output_3.fasta > output_4.fasta
perl -pe 'BEGIN { our $i = 1; } s/>/">Seq".($i++)/ge;' < output_4.fasta
```